# Using lists in if and else statements: Hangman as an example

Tags: python, if-statement, append

Currently, I've been working on creating a hangman game and I've managed to get the majority of the scripts working and running perfectly however, I'm having problems with using lists in statements as I'd like to make a list of "used letters" which stops you from using the same letter again. The problem I've been finding is that I'll either set it up so it always includes the guess variable and not the input or it just doesn't work and I get a syntax error. Any suggestions on how I should do it?

Below, you'll find the code:

```
from random import randint
ans = input(">>>>>Let's play the word guessing game!<<<<<")
ans_upper = ans.upper()
if ans_upper == "YES":
    print("Good because that's what we're going to play!")
else:
    print("Tough, because we're going to play hangman anyways!")
#---#---#---#---#---#---#---#---#---#---# RANDOM WORD #---#---#---#---#---#---#---#
x = randint(1,15)
if x == 1:
    word = "bubblegum"
elif x == 2:
    word = "pasta"
elif x == 3:
    word = "cow"
elif x == 4:
    word = "chicken"
elif x == 5:
    word = "milk"
elif x == 6:
    word = "chair"
elif x == 7:
word = "computer"
elif x == 8:
    word = "psychology"
elif x == 9:
    word = "clock"
elif x == 10:
    word = "melon"
elif x == 11:
    word == "word"
elif x == 12:
    word = "brackets"
elif x == 13:
    word = "hangman"
elif x == 14:
    word = "paper"
elif x == 15:
    word = "internet"
else:
    print("ERROR: NUMBER HAS EXCEEDED THE VALUE OF 15")
#---#---#---#---#---#---#---#---#---# MYSTERY LETTERS #---#---#---#---#---#---#--
blanks = list("-"*len(word))
print("Can you guess the word, there are " , len(word), " letters!")
print(''.join(blanks))
word_list = list(word)
#---#---#---#---#---#---#---#---#---# LOOPING #---#---#---#---#---#---#---#---#---
loop = True
finished = len(word) * 1
done = 1
used = [] #This is for the used letters
while loop == True:
    guess = str(input("Enter a letter!"))
    checker = len(guess)
    if checker == 1:
        for letter_index in range(len(word_list)):
           if guess in word_list[letter_index]:
                guess_index = word_list.index(guess)
                letter_index = guess_index
                blanks[guess_index] = guess
                done = done + 1
                print("".join(blanks))

        if done == finished:
            print("You win!")
           loop = False
            break

    elif checker > 1:
        print("Hey, guess one letter at a time!")
```

So, the area that I'd like to have assigned to the task of storing the used letters us labeled as "used". I know that it involves the `.append()` command but I'm not sure where it'd go and how exactly I'd write out the command.
Thanks in advance,
Richard

Comment: Oh and I should mention, I know there are more efficient ways of storing the words but I chose to do it this way because it seemed more fun to do and I wanted to get some experience using the import function in Python. Secondly, the break is there as well as the loop = False because I wanted to be sure it'd end even though I added a break as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two tidbits you need to know.  First, append is what you want to add the new guess into used:

```
used = []
guess = 'x'
used.append(guess)
print used
```

['x']

And second, to see if the guess has already been used, use 'in':

```
print guess in used
```

True

So you'd probably want to do something like this:

```
if guess in used:
    print "You already guessed that!"
else:
    used.append(guess)
    ...
```

Comment: That does work, however, one of the problems I'm having with this is that if the word has the same letter more than once e.g "Psychology", the O only appears in the first part of the word and not the second. It also stops the user from being allowed to enter O because it's in the used list. Any tips for solving this?